# Has PDF file generated through Crystal Report anything to do with Adobe installed in the local machine?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-export

I am generating PDF file using Crystal report ExportToDisk method in VB.NET 3.5.
Locally and on integration environment generated PDF file is much readable i.e.font size is good.
But the PDF file generated on production environment is different in formatting.The lines are wrapping and font size is also little small.

There is not Adobe installed on integration.

What may be causing this issue.Any suggestion?

Comment: Are the fonts used in the report available/installed on the production machine?

Answer (score 0):

Most reporting tools try and default page sizes and setting to the local default printer, or set specifically through code if this is not present, you could check that for page size.

If you are using a specific font, you may need to install that on the server.

There should be no dependency to Adobe Acrobat/Reader.

Comment: I have not set the page size or font for the PDF generated in the code.I am using ReportDocument.ExportToDisk() method.